# Text internationalization in Javascript using liferay-ui:message

Tags: javascript, internationalization, liferay

How can I do internationalization for this :

```
alert('<liferay-ui:message key="please-choose-file-type" />');
```

Notice that I want to internationalize the message inside Alert using Liferay:ui:message tag.

Thanks.

Comment: You can run it by... running it. What's your real question? "How can I internationalize the contents of a Javascript string?" maybe?

Comment: you can use something like this <%= UnicodeLanguageUtil.get(pageContext, "please-choose-file-type") %>

Comment: @QPaysTaxes yes exactly!

Comment: @wikimix I converted my comment into answer. If it helps you in solving the issue please accept it so that other users can also refer it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comment into answer :)

Hi,

You can try this code snippet

```
<%= UnicodeLanguageUtil.get(pageContext, "please-choose-file-type") %>
```

HTH

Comment: Please show how to use that snippet and remove the various addenda ("Hi", "converting my...", "HTH")

Comment: Can we get rid of scriplets?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is :

```
alert('<%= UnicodeLanguageUtil.get(pageContext, "please-choose-file-type"") %>');
```

Comment: So you are using js inside a jsp file, do you know a way to do this in a js file?

Comment: @EduardoPérez You must declare your js file into liferray-portlet.js file within <footer-portlet-javascript> tag like follows :`<footer-portlet-javascript>/js/file.js</footer-portlet-javascript>`